# Selenium Python find span by data-testid="menu"

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, whatsapp

I'm newbie with selenium and for learning I'm trying to move inside Whatsapp web and download image from a conversation... The idea come from some tutorial on the web but they doesn't work.
I'm using python 3.8

i need to press a button for open the menu and it is identified by

```
    <span data-testid="menu" data-icon="menu" class="">
       <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24" height="24">
          <pathfill="currentColor" d="M12 7a2 2 0 1 0-.001-4.001A2 2 0 0 0 12 7zm0 2a2 2 0 1 0-.001 3.999A2 2 0 0 0 12 9zm0 6a2 2 0 1 0-.001 3.999A2 2 0 0 0 12 15z"></path>
       </svg>
    </span>
```

I have tryed several way to do this, as an example i post 2 attempts:

```
    menu = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@data-testid= \"menu\"]")
    menu = self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector("span[@data-testid='menu']")
    menu = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@title= \"menu\"]/span")
```

edit:
The message error I receive is:

```
Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//span[@title= "menu"]"}
  (Session info: chrome=86.0.4240.111)
```

Can someone please help me with this problem?

Comment: Replace *"doesn't work"* with an actual issue description

Comment: Remove the space in `"//span[@data-testid= \"menu\"]"`. Use `"//span[@data-testid=\"menu\"]"`

Comment: Try This : `driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@data-testid='menu']")`

Comment: what is the actual error?

Comment: The message error I receive is                                                                          Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//span[@title= "menu"]"}
  (Session info: chrome=86.0.4240.111)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you have 'self' in there and those backslashes? I'd say your second try was close to being correct, but use xpath, not CSS Selector, and don't forget the two forward slashes before 'span':

```
menu = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@data-testid='menu']")
```